# PyCharm: Using a docker container to set up the python interpreter but with `--cpuset-cpus`

Tags: docker, pycharm, multiprocessing

I have followed the JetBrains instructions to set up a python interpreter from a docker container image. My problem is that the interpreter appears to be using just one CPU when more are available on my machine. I want to be able to use more processors using the `--cpuset-cpus` argument but I can't find anywhere to pass that when configuring the interpreter.

Is there another way to do this? Or is it a current limitation that pycharm has?

Comment: Are you using Docker Desktop for Mac?

Comment: You might want to link to the JetBrains instructions you are referring to

Comment: What makes you think it's only using one core? Are you running python scripts? Python has a ['GIL', 'Global Interpreter Lock'](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which makes python single threaded (my biggest complaint with python). Usage of multiple cores is non trivial in python

Comment: > Are you using Docker Desktop for Mac? 

@NickODell yes I am

Comment: > What makes you think it's only using one core?

@nanotek Yes, the scripts take way too long...

Comment: I figured it out... let me post the answer.

Comment: @ChristosHadjinikolis I ask because the mac version has a setting to [limit the number of cores](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/#resources).

Comment: It was just about increasing resources in the docker desktop app

Answer (score 0):

So... after a bit of googling and a lot of trial and error, here is what I managed to do.

1. If you try to just use a dockerfile to setup a python interpreter in a docker image, you cant handle the image's deployment. Suppose you want to use the below `dockerfile`:

   ```
   ARG BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.4

   ############
   # Builder layer
   FROM python:${BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION}-slim-buster as builder

   WORKDIR /vsm

   # Install Requirements
   ## Copy Files
   COPY pip.conf .
   COPY requirements.txt .
   COPY requirements-dev.txt .
   ARG PIP_CONFIG_FILE=pip.conf

   ## Download dependencies locally
   RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
       pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && \
       pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements-dev.txt \
   ```

   In PyCharm the interface would look like this:

   [image]
2. This does not allow you to pass arguments like: `cpus`
3. A way to bypass this problem is to use `docker-compose.yaml`. So suppose you have the following files in the root directory of your repo.

   ```
   ...
   ├── dev.Dockerfile    # contains the above code from bullet 1
   ├── docker-compose.yml
   ...
   ```

   and the `docker-compose.yaml` is defined as follows:

   ```
   ---
   version: "3.9"

   services:
     dev-env:
       build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
       volumes:
         - .:/Users/Vortexa/Github/bon-voyage  # Mount the current directory using the host's absolute path
       deploy:
         resources:
           limits:
             cpus: '8'
             memory: 16384M
   ```
4. Then if you choose the docker-compose option instead from the drop-down list that pycharm offers:

   [image]

   and select `dev-env` as the service to deploy then the docker environment will be build and deployed with access to the specified CPUs and memory.
5. There is a chance that you will get an error saying that the requested resources are not available. If you do have more cores and memory to use on your machine, then it is just a matter of configuring resources for your docker engine:

   [image]

Hope this helps someone who will come looking!